# issue with geography

Tags: sql, asp.net

```
PolyColl.GeogCol1.STIntersects(GEOGRAPHY::Point(174.81169160000002,-41.3289746,4326))

A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.
System.FormatException: 
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Point(Double latitude, Double longitude, Int32 srid)
```

.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Please include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code that can reproduce the error you see.

Comment: @warpred, I added the code.

Comment: Since the latitude comes first in the constructor, you possibly meant `GEOGRAPHY::Point(-41.3289746,4326, 174.81169160000002)`.

Comment: @Wiktor, I'm using (long,lat) patterns, because my polygon added in that.
It's working for the all regions, except New zealand